# How to prevent play video using file path of window azure media server without login?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud, media

Currently doing one project basis on Windows Azure Media Service .

Scenario-
There is a media player on website, which play video source file of media contains on Azure media server.

Requirement -

**1) Unregistered user or without login user can't play video using azure media file path**.
(It is better for me without use of Active directory credential and If we can upload that video encrypted format and play with decryption when user is logged in)

### Please provide proper guidance which satisfy above requirement.

What we have done - Flag/notify me if I am doing wrong way

1) Tried to media upload as encrypted format and using token but unable to decrypt that video using token access.

2) I think, if there is some mechanism like session variable maintain azure media server which check user is authenticated then give rights to access
then problem become solve ? But don't know how to use that.

I have read many of articles/blog , gone through many of internet available source code but unable to find best way.
or What we do next ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option you took should work. You could encrypt your video file using either AES or PlayReady, and config Token Authentication for your content key - which means decryption key is only issued when your player present the correct token. Could you specify why the video can't be decrypted? was your token wrong or the key was wrong? I have a blog for troubleshooting AES encryption configuration: http://mingfeiy.com/debug-aes-encrypted-stream-azure-media-services. And let me know whether you made it work.

Cheers,
Mingfei Yan

Comment: Hi Mingfie Yan,
Many many thank you for quick support.

Yes its work as following http://mingfeiy.com/debug-aes-encrypted-stream-azure-media-services

There is mentioned "Azure Media Services Explorer" tool which has user friendly step by step functionality covered.

From these tool, I got knowledge, way of use - how to play encrypted video.

Now It's working via encrypted video playing through silverlight pluggin + OSMF Player.

Thanks you so much once again !!!

Comment: Thank you Mingfie Yan..it worked for me!!!!. Further i am searching a player which can play encrypted media with token authorization from azure, across windows,Mac, Iphone,Ipad and android. Media is encrypted with Playready DRM, + simple web token authorization.

Comment: @MingfeiYan, as the token is public and can be easily shared by authenticated user to any other user. Is there any way to prevent this? Thanks for the help in advance!